# Mondrian using fact table instead of dimension to gather dimentions

Tags: pentaho, dimensions, mondrian, impala

I am testing Pentaho 5.3 with Impala. My schema defines a dimension by relating it to its dimension table. However, when I try to use the Filter mondrian tries to obtain the dimensions from the fact table and since the table it is big it takes a long time just to load the dimensions to filter by. I do use the approxRowCount in my dimension definition.
I also have an instillation of Pentaho 5.0 with PG using a similar dataset and exact same schema and when I use the filter dimensions are loaded instantaneously. So it seems to me the issue is not schema related.

Could anyone tell me if this behavior (when trying to use Filter mondrian aggregating dimension data from the fact table instead of dimension table) is due to Pentaho settings or what could cause it?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else ever wonders about this behavior it could be related to the fact that joins are much more efficient in PG than a NoSql database like Impala. I though that when using the Filter mondrian obtains the dimensions from the dimension table if provided with one. However, it seems it does a join of dimension and fact table before displaying dimensions. 
Hope that helps!